# passing data from activity to fragment(navigation-component)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I have an activity through that I want to pass the data to a fragment. I am managing the fragments by the navigation component. Please guide me on how can i pass the data to fragments from my activity. thank you in advance

**CODE FOR MAINACTIVITY.JAVA WHICH HOLDS FRAGMENT**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    bnView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bnView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.container);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bnView, navController);

}
```

this is the mainactivity where all the fragments are but before that i have a login activity through that i went inside the OTPActivity and through otp activity i enter inside the MAIN ACTIVITY.

**CODE FOR THE LOGIN ACTIVITY**

```
  binding.otpGetingBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String vall = binding.editTextPhone.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
            if (!ValidatePhoneNum()) {
                return;
            }else
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginSignupActivity.this, OTPActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("mobile", vall);
                startActivity(intent);
                

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Does the Activity hold the NavController or is the Activity opened from Fragment?

Comment: no this activity is diffrent it does not hold that fragment

Comment: How are you starting the Fragment/Activity using Intent, NavController.Navigate, ect. ? Please show code.

Comment: @JavierRefuerzo please check sir

Comment: So you want data passed to the fragments in the MainActivity from OTPActivity/LoginSignupActivity?  Was the MainActivity Started first before LoginSignupActivity?  The code above does not show where MainActivity is started, so if passing data from one Activity to another show the Intent. If Main Activity was started first you may want to use onActivityResult.

Comment: MainActicity started from OTPActivity. First of all  LOGINACTIVITY->OTPACTIVITY->MAINACTIVITY, YES and I want to pass data from LoginActivity to the fragments in the MainActivity, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data to the MainActivity in a bundle/intent then get the bundle/intent in the fragment.

From Fragment class:

```
    Intent intent = requireActivity().getIntent();
    if (intent == null) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Intent is null");
        return;
    }
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle == null) {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "bundle is: NULL");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: sir sorry but I did not get it completely please elaborate more.

Comment: When MainActivity is launched with an intent pass the data in the intent.  From the fragment call requireActivty().getIntent(),  requireActivity() will get MainActivity, getIntent() will get the intent used to launch MainActivity.